# Why does Observable.empty() not propagate onComplete() downstream?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

The [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html) for RxJava `Observable.empty()` tells:

> create an Observable that emits no items but terminates normally

"Terminate normally" means calling `onComplete()`.

So in the downstream observer, I expect to receive `onComplete()`. But this doesn't happen.

Any ideas why? Does "terminates normally" mean something else in this context?

Here is a sample code:

```
Observable.just(2, 3, 0, 15, 12, 1)
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<String> apply(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    if (integer == 0) {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    } else {
                        return Observable.just("Value: " + integer);
                    }
                }
            })
            .subscribe(observer);
```

`observer` doesn't receive `onComplete()`.

Comment: You cannot stop a `flatMap` by returning an `Observable.empty()` in the mapper function. `flatMap` merges sources until all sources are done, irrespective how many elements each of them has. If you want to stop the flow in general, use one of the `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `Observable` type as an example, what `flatMap` actually does is:

1. *maps* each emission from upstream into an `Observable<T>`, which effectively converts the entire stream to an `Observable<Observable<T>>`. to spare you from "callback hell"-like syntax, it then...
2. *flattens* that stream into simply `Observable<T>`

(i've always thought the name `flatMap` seemed backwards for this reason)

so, using your sample input, the *map* operation would produce:

```
2  --> Observable(2)
3  --> Observable(3) 
0  --> Observable()
15 --> Observable(15)
12 --> Observable(12)
1  --> Observable(1)
```

at this point the stream is now `Observable<Observable<Integer>>`.

subsequently *flattening* the inner `Observable<Integer>` emissions yields a stream that is effectively the same as:

```
Observable(2, 3, 15, 12, 1)
```

...since `Observable.empty()` produces nothing.

as i understand your question, you were thinking that the 0 emission would effectively terminate the entire stream, but that's not how `flatMap` works. if, however, that is the behavior you seek, i think some variation of `switch*` operator might be more appropriate for you.

i hope that helps you along!

Answer (score 1):

There's probably some other problem with your code since observable empty does call onComplete.

Here a simple test to check this (in kotlin):

```
class RxObservableTest {

    @Test
    fun checkObservable() {
        Observable.empty<Int>()
                .doOnComplete { println("Received OnComplete") }
                .test()
                .assertComplete()
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63929', transport: 'socket'
Received OnComplete
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63929', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Update**

So i guess i understand your problem now.

You expect to receive onCompleted after each `Observable` is completed but that's not how RxJava works.
From observer [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html):

> and the invocation pattern must adhere to the following protocol:
>
> onSubscribe onNext* (onError | onComplete)?

That means that each `Observer` will receive not more than one onComplete event and after that in won't receive anything. In this case it is received after all of the `Observable`s in `flatMap` are completed. In your case the last one emits 1 and exactly the output you see.

In case you want to be notified of the completion of `Observable.empty()` you may consider providing more complex data that just an `Integer`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Updated question with a code sample which clarifies my case.

Comment: @andrei How do you check whether subscriber did receive onComplete? A've made a test case for your code and onComplete is definately received

Comment: I just log the onComplete() call inside observer. onComplete() is received after emitting the last item(1), but not when flat-mapping to Observable.empty().

Comment: @andrei I've updated my answer. See if that makes things clear for you.